Access Files in Bin/Release folder deployed to Azure App Service Linux using C#
I am storing some json files in my code which are published to Azure App service.
previously the app service plan was based on Windows OS and I was able to easily access the files using.
var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
string data=File.ReadAllText(path+"/"+"file.json");

however i am facing now that after changing the app service plan to Linux, the above code no longer works.
Is there another way to access ?

Instead of path+"/"+"file.json" try Path.Combine(path, "file.json")

Where does your json file reside?Once check the KUDU Console for confirmation.

The code which you gave work only if the json file is available in the site/wwwroot directory.

By default the application folders/files are deployed to site/wwwroot directory. As you are looking for the bin folder, the path will differ.

Below code worked for me in Local, Windows and Linux App service.
 var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
 string TFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "file.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
 .FirstOrDefault();
 string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(TFile);


Make sure the files are available in the bin folder.

Output:

